# How to slice a 2d matrix using lists in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

In this example:

```
In [19]: a[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]].shape
Out[19]: (3,)

In [20]: a[1:4,1:4].shape
Out[20]: (3, 3)

In [21]: a.shape
Out[21]: (100, 100)
```

Why Out[19] is not (3,3)?
The reason that I want to use list is because I want to do something like this:

```
a[[1,8,12],[34,45,50]].shape
```

So that the result would be a (3,3) matrix.

Comment: I believe what you want to do with fancy indexing here only works with range objects, not arrays of individual row/column indices.

Comment: Your `a[<list>,<list>]` attempts will do a zip-like operation, where your resulting array will be `[a[1,1], a[2,2], a[3,3]]` -- this is why it's not 3x3 but 3x1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perfect use case for [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html):

```
a[np.ix_([1,8,12],[34,45,50])]
```

**Demo**

```
a = np.arange(5 * 5).reshape(5, 5)    
a[np.ix_([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])]

array([[ 6,  7,  8],
       [11, 12, 13],
       [16, 17, 18]])
```

Comment: And more efficient than `a[[1,2,3],:][:,[1,2,3]]`